# How to create a flow that runs through each contact on the task, and adds them to the campaign members

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, tasks, campaign, campaign-member

**Business requirement**

1. A process that starts a flow
2. A flow that runs through each contact on the task, and adds them to the campaign.
3. Campaign Members created in this way should have their own special status.

Comment: Hi Kathy, welcome to SFSE. Have you had a chance to look at [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)? Right now, your question reads like you're looking for someone to do an implementation for you. We look for questions that are specific, detailed, and show the work you've done so far so we can help where you're stuck.

Comment: Sounds interesting! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a process builder that will call a visual flow and pass in your task and campaign Ids into your flow. From there use a Flow Record Lookup element that will get the related contact records and store them in a sObject collection. From there you could create a campaign member record for each contact and update the status as needed.

Comment: Contact does not have a lookup to Campaign Member. The relationship is the other way around; Campaign Member is a junction object between Contact/Lead and Campaign.